# "WshShell The system cannot find the file specified Error 80070002"

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to create some CSV files which are then used as references so that a batch file can use them as inputs. I have succeeded in making this work but found that I needed the VBA code to wait for the script to complete before continuing. From what I found on the web I should use the Windows Script Host Object Model" which would then allow me to set WaitOnReturn:=True. However I now get "Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)': Automation Error   The system cannot find the file specified." This is obviously something elementary that I have missed but it is taking me hours to work out what it is. I have searched and not found an answer that seems to help. Here is the code that works, followed by the code that fails. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
Public Sub Create_run_delete_batch_file(Input_File)

    Const MY_FILENAME = "E:\Test.bat"

    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim retVal As Variant

    FileNumber = FreeFile

     'create batch file
    Open MY_FILENAME For Output As #FileNumber
    Print #FileNumber, "E:"
    Print #FileNumber, "cd " & Chr(34) & "E:\Test_Dir\" & Chr(34) 
    'Set Current Risk File here
    Print #FileNumber, "Script that works goes here" & Input_File
    Close #FileNumber

     'run batch file
    retVal = Shell(MY_FILENAME, vbNormalFocus)

     ' NOTE THE BATCH FILE WILL RUN, BUT THE CODE WILL CONTINUE TO RUN.
    If retVal = 0 Then
        MsgBox "An Error Occured"
        Close #FileNumber
        End
    End If

     'Delete batch file
    Kill MY_FILENAME

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub Create_run_delete_batch_file(Input_File)

    Const MY_FILENAME = "E:\Test.bat"

    Dim FileNumber As Integer
    Dim retVal As Variant
    Dim wsh As WshShell
    Set wsh = New WshShell

    FileNumber = FreeFile

     'create batch file
    Open MY_FILENAME For Output As #FileNumber
    Print #FileNumber, "E:"
    Print #FileNumber, "cd " & Chr(34) & "E:\Test_Dir\" & Chr(34) 
    'Set Current Risk File here
    Print #FileNumber, "Script that works goes here" & Input_File
    Close #FileNumber

     'run batch file
    'retVal = Shell(MY_FILENAME, vbNormalFocus)
    retVal = wsh.Run(MY_FILENAME, WaitOnReturn:=True)

     ' NOTE THE BATCH FILE WILL RUN, BUT THE CODE WILL CONTINUE TO RUN.
    If retVal = 0 Then
        MsgBox "An Error Occured"
        Close #FileNumber
        End
    End If

     'Delete batch file
    Kill MY_FILENAME

End Sub
```

Comment: For your `WshShell` version which line throws the error?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but why are you closing the file handle twice?